# Maven build failing with 'is not a valid directory'

Tags: ant, jenkins, weblogic, maven-3, osb

I am trying to use Jenkins to build a maven project (same failure at cmd line!) and I get the below error. I can't see any permissions issues and have tried several changes to permissions to see if it is a linux side error but no luck? Any ideas?

```
export:
     [echo] midleware.home = /u01/Oracle/Middleware
Property "export.log.dir" has not been set
     [echo] export log dir = ${export.log.dir}
     [java] Executing '/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_30/jre/bin/java' with arguments:
     [java] '-XX:MaxPermSize=256m'
     [java] '-Xmx768m'
     [java] '-Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true'
     [java] '-Dweblogic.home=/u01/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3'
     [java] '-Dharvester.home=/u01/Oracle/Middleware/osb_11/harvester'
     [java] '-Dosb.home=/u01/Oracle/Middleware/osb_11'
     [java] '-Dosgi.bundlefile.limit=500'
     [java] '-Dosgi.nl=en_US'
     [java] '-Dmiddleware.home=/u01/Oracle/Middleware'
     [java] '-Dosgi.logfile=/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/01_export-atas-osbconfig/osbflows/atas/export.log'
     [java] '-jar'
     [java] '/u01/Oracle/Middleware/oepe/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar'
     [java] '-data'
     [java] '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/01_export-atas-osbconfig/osbflows/atas'
     [java] '-application'
     [java] 'com.bea.alsb.core.ConfigExport'
     [java] '-configProject'
     [java] 'ATAS_Configuration'
     [java] '-configJar'
     [java] '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/01_export-atas-osbconfig/osbflows/atas/target/atas-10.0.jar'
     [java] '-includeDependencies'
     [java] 'true'
     [java] '-debug'
     [java] 
     [java] The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
     [java] not part of the command.
      [ant] Exiting /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/01_export-atas-osbconfig/build/ant/osb-config-export.xml.

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 14.698s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Mar 27 14:00:50 GMT 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/56M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.6:run (export-osb-configuration) on project atas: An Ant BuildException has occured: The following error occurred while executing this line:
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/01_export-atas-osbconfig/build/ant/osb-config-export.xml:12: /u01/Oracle/Middleware/oepe is not a valid directory
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.6:run (export-osb-configuration) on project atas: An Ant BuildException has occured: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/01_export-atas-osbconfig/build/ant/osb-config-export.xml:12: /u01/Oracle/Middleware/oepe is not a valid directory
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:317)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:152)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven31Launcher.main(Maven31Launcher.java:132)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:330)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:238)
    at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven31Main.launch(Maven31Main.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:134)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:69)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An Ant BuildException has occured: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/01_export-atas-osbconfig/build/ant/osb-config-export.xml:12: /u01/Oracle/Middleware/oepe is not a valid directory
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AntRunMojo.execute(AntRunMojo.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/01_export-atas-osbconfig/osbflows/atas/target/antrun/build-main.xml:9: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/01_export-atas-osbconfig/build/ant/osb-config-export.xml:12: /u01/Oracle/Middleware/oepe is not a valid directory
    at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuildException(ProjectHelper.java:551)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:444)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor16.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AntRunMojo.execute(AntRunMojo.java:270)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/01_export-atas-osbconfig/build/ant/osb-config-export.xml:12: /u01/Oracle/Middleware/oepe is not a valid directory
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.setupWorkingDir(Java.java:855)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.setupExecutable(Java.java:825)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.fork(Java.java:788)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:214)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:135)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.execute(Java.java:108)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor16.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:442)
    ... 44 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/01_export-atas-osbconfig/osbflows/atas/pom.xml to uk.org.tlms.tlmsim.flows/atas/10.0/atas-10.0.pom
channel stopped

Finished: FAILURE
```

xml file as requeted

```
<project name="osb-config-export" default="export">
    <property file="${export.properties.file}"/>

        <target name="delete-metadata">
                <delete dir="${workspace.dir}/.metadata"/>
        </target>

    <target name="export" depends="delete-metadata">
                <echo message="midleware.home = ${middleware.home}"/>
                <echo message="export log dir = ${export.log.dir}"/>
                <java dir="${middleware.home}/oepe" jar="${middleware.home}/oepe/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar"
                   fork="true"  failonerror="true" maxmemory="768m">
                        <jvmarg line="-XX:MaxPermSize=256m" />
                        <arg line="-data ${workspace.dir}"/>
                        <arg line="-application com.bea.alsb.core.ConfigExport"/>
                        <arg line="-configProject ${config.project}"/>
                        <!--<arg line="-configSubProjects ${config.subprojects}"/>-->
                        <arg line="-configJar ${config.jar}"/>
                        <arg line="-includeDependencies  ${config.includeDependencies}"/>
                        <arg line="-debug"/>
                        <sysproperty key="sun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax" value="true"/>
                        <sysproperty key="weblogic.home" value="${middleware.home}/wlserver_10.3"/>
                        <sysproperty key="harvester.home" value="${middleware.home}/osb_11/harvester"/>
                        <sysproperty key="osb.home" value="${middleware.home}/osb_11"/>
                        <sysproperty key="osgi.bundlefile.limit" value="500"/>
                        <sysproperty key="osgi.nl" value="en_US"/>
                        <sysproperty key="middleware.home" value="${middleware.home}"/>
                        <!--sysproperty key="osgi.logfile" value="${export.log.dir}/export.log"/-->
                        <sysproperty key="osgi.logfile" value="${workspace.dir}/export.log"/>
        </java>
        </target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, as you yourself pointed out, this is the error:

`[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/01_export-atas-osbconfig/build/ant/osb-config-export.xml:12: /u01/Oracle/Middleware/oepe is not a valid directory`

You also say that the same error happens from command line, so this is not an issue with Jenkins's user permissions, Jenkins environment variables or workspace

You need to look at the code on `line 12` of `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/01_export-atas-osbconfig/build/ant/osb-config-export.xml`. Please edit that file into the original question.

But it seems pretty obvious, it cannot access `/u01/Oracle/Middleware/oepe`. What happens when you just open command prompt and do `cd /u01/Oracle/Middleware/oepe`?

There is also this:
`Property "export.log.dir" has not been set`
I don't know if you are expecting that error or not. Looks like you need to provide an additional property value.

***Edit 1:***
So, if the `cd /u01/Oracle/Middleware/oepe` works from command line and the structure looks good, it could be filesystem permissions. Try executing your **maven** command with a `sudo` in front of it. If that works, then we will need to look closer at permissions.

Secondly, try executing the `java` command outside of the ant script, on command line, from within `/u01/Oracle/Middleware/oepe`:

`/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_30/jre/bin/java -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xmx768m -Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true -Dweblogic.home=/u01/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3 -Dharvester.home=/u01/Oracle/Middleware/osb_11/harvester -Dosb.home=/u01/Oracle/Middleware/osb_11 -Dosgi.bundlefile.limit=500 -Dosgi.nl=en_US -Dmiddleware.home=/u01/Oracle/Middleware -Dosgi.logfile=/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/01_export-atas-osbconfig/osbflows/atas/export.log -jar /u01/Oracle/Middleware/oepe/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar -data /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/01_export-atas-osbconfig/osbflows/atas -application com.bea.alsb.core.ConfigExport -configProject ATAS_Configuration -configJar /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/01_export-atas-osbconfig/osbflows/atas/target/atas-10.0.jar -includeDependencies true -debug`

Comment: Hi,added the xml, cd is fine and the directory structure below it is complete as well (it then should go to get a .jar from oepe/plugins). export.log.dir is a red herring, i've added it in my latest run but no change.

Comment: Try temporary using `sudo` (this will show if it's a permission error), and then try running the `java` command directly on command line from within that directory. I've updated the answer with details. @RickSparks

Answer (score 0):

I only have general advice in this situation--try to pinpoint where the error is coming from.  We're seeing an error that's coming out of a combination of Maven, the Maven Ant plugin (I assume), Jenkins, and the actual Java command that's calling the OSB export.  Break it down to the simplest one first (just call the java command yourself to see what works), then layer on top of it until you find where the breakage is occuring.

For instance, I don't know whether what is being logged to the console is actually the same `java` command it's calling, or if that's something you're logging yourself by guessing at the call:

```
 [java] Executing '/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_30/jre/bin/java' with arguments:
 [java] '-XX:MaxPermSize=256m'
 [java] '-Xmx768m'
 [java] '-Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true'
 [java] '-Dweblogic.home=/u01/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3'
 [java] '-Dharvester.home=/u01/Oracle/Middleware/osb_11/harvester'
 [java] '-Dosb.home=/u01/Oracle/Middleware/osb_11'
 [java] '-Dosgi.bundlefile.limit=500'
 [java] '-Dosgi.nl=en_US'
 [java] '-Dmiddleware.home=/u01/Oracle/Middleware'
 [java] '-Dosgi.logfile=/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/01_export-atas-osbconfig/osbflows/atas/export.log'
 [java] '-jar'
 [java] '/u01/Oracle/Middleware/oepe/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar'
 [java] '-data'
 [java] '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/01_export-atas-osbconfig/osbflows/atas'
 [java] '-application'
 [java] 'com.bea.alsb.core.ConfigExport'
 [java] '-configProject'
 [java] 'ATAS_Configuration'
 [java] '-configJar'
 [java] '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/01_export-atas-osbconfig/osbflows/atas/target/atas-10.0.jar'
 [java] '-includeDependencies'
 [java] 'true'
 [java] '-debug'
```

First, take that and call it yourself as the same user that Jenkins is running as.  That would let you know whether you're even able to call this:

`/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_30/jre/bin/java -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xmx768m -Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true -Dweblogic.home=/u01/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3 -Dharvester.home=/u01/Oracle/Middleware/osb_11/harvester -Dosb.home=/u01/Oracle/Middleware/osb_11 -Dosgi.bundlefile.limit=500 -Dosgi.nl=en_US -Dmiddleware.home=/u01/Oracle/Middleware -Dosgi.logfile=/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/01_export-atas-osbconfig/osbflows/atas/export.log -jar /u01/Oracle/Middleware/oepe/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar -data /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/01_export-atas-osbconfig/osbflows/atas -application com.bea.alsb.core.ConfigExport -configProject ATAS_Configuration -configJar /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/01_export-atas-osbconfig/osbflows/atas/target/atas-10.0.jar -includeDependencies true -debug`

Then, call the ant script that's doing that as the Jenkins user

Then, call the Maven plugin as the Jekins user,

then Jenkins itself

Don't **walk down** to the simplest solution, start there and walk up.